# ealsticsearch : two nodes with the same cluster name having two different cluster uuid

Tags: elasticsearch

I configured two node with the cluster name (production), but when I installed head plugin I didn't see the two nodes. I saw the node which it's address is used to open head plugin

For instance : `9200/_plugin/head` will show me the node1 as master and as the only node in the cluster, the same thing goes for the node2.

My configuration :

**node1 :**

```
cluster.name: production
index.numer_of_shards : 5
index .number_of_replicas : 0
node.name: node1
network.host: node1 Ip Add
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [node1 Ip Add ,node2 Ip Add]
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discover.zen.ping.timeout: 20s
```

**node2 :**

```
cluster.name: production
index.numer_of_shards : 5
index .number_of_replicas : 0
network.host: node2 Ip Add
node.name: node2
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [node1 Ip Add ,node2 Ip Add]
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discover.zen.ping.timeout: 20s
```

Comment: `node.name: node1` is same in both host

Comment: i just made a mistake its node2 for the second node in the real configuration file.   What is the default port for Zendiscovery (when no port is specified in discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts )

Comment: i found the problem : the ports 9300 to 9400 were blocked by the firewall

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post but had the same issue. I solved it with theses 3 steps:

1. Opening **ports range 9300 to 9400** on all machines.
2. Delete all the data from the folder **/elasticsearch_installation_folder/data/** on all machines (seems to be */var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/* on linux)
3. **Restart** all *elastic search* nodes.